# Create table from existing table but drop fields that have too much missing data SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to create a new table from an existing where I filter for specific criteria. The new table should drop fields (columns) in the original table where 50% or more of the row values are missing per column (IS NULL), and then some more basic criteria like column A and B row values must not be empty. The exact criteria for filtering is:

1. Drop any columns where 50% or more of the column data is missing
2. Column E must be between 50 and 100
3. Column A and B must have a row value
4. Column F must be between 200 to 1000

Below is just a sample to of table A (original table) and the filtered table B after criteria 1-4 are applied.

Original Table (A):

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D | Col_E | Col_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy | rs | NULL | NULL | 55 | 500 |
| xx | NULL | NULL | NULL | 65 | 845 |
| NULL | rt | x33 | NULL | 120 | 100 |
| xz | rz | NULL | NULL | 80 | 300 |
| xw | rp | NULL | NULL | 10 | 90 |

New table (B) from existing table:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_E | Col_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy | rs | 55 | 500 |
| xz | rz | 80 | 300 |

My problem is I know how to filter the data for criteria 2, 3 and 4 as shown below, but I don't know how to go through each column and check if the column has 50% or more NULL values or missing values in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE B
AS SELECT * FROM A
WHERE (Col_A != "" AND Col_B != "") 
  AND (Col_E >= 50 AND Col_E <= 100) 
  AND (Col_F >= 200 AND Col_F <= 1000);
```

I found a way to check my NULL values in a separate query like this:

```
SELECT 
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(Col_A))/COUNT(*) AS NULL_A,
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(Col_B))/COUNT(*) AS NULL_B,
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(Col_C))/COUNT(*) AS NULL_C,
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(Col_D))/COUNT(*) AS NULL_D,
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(Col_E))/COUNT(*) AS NULL_E,
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(Col_F))/COUNT(*) AS NULL_F
FROM A;
```

The output of this table will tell me the number of missing values in each column. But how can I incorporate this into my original query with the other WHERE conditions I have? Is that even possible? Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your database tags look incompatible.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I removed sql-server and apache spark sql. I am working on GCP with the zepplin notebook but just using ANSI sql. Please let me know if my tags need any other changes, thanks!

Comment: Have to dynamically build SQL statement string for inclusion of only fields that meet 50%+ criteria. Make that determination with If Then or CASE structure. Can you build stored procedures?  No idea how to pull percentages from aggregate query. In Access VBA I would use DLookup().

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep) and I am able to drop columns having > 50% NULL values and I believe this might fit in your requirement.

Here are the steps you can follow,

1. Go to dataprep from cloud console, accept all terms and conditions
2. In the dataprep home Create a flow

[image]

3. Connect to your data & import your datasets, click import and add to flow

[image]

4. Data will be added to recipe, click on the recipe to transform/edit your data

[image]

5. You’ll be able to see your data on dataprep canvas

[image]

6. You’ll be able to see all columns, their data type, no. of valid & missing values at the top (ie the above dataset, the greyed out bar shows no. of missing values.

[image]

7. Select the columns with more no. of missing values and delete.

[image]

8. After all the transformations Click the Run button on the top right corner.
9. Choose the output destination of the resultant data
10. You can choose a running environment either as Dataflow or Trifacta.
11. Finally Click Run.You will get your resultant data in the specified destination.

For more understanding follow this lab on [Qwiklabs](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/4415?parent=catalog) or video on
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3m9gH7i8oM)